# Calling prestashop webservices returns "Parameter must be an array

Tags: prestashop

When calling a client's prestashop webservices with the url:
https://www.shop.com/api/categories?display=full"

I get the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<thirtybees xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<errors>
<error>
<code><![CDATA[3]]></code>
<message><![CDATA[[PHP Warning #2] count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (/home/xyz/public_html/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php, line 927)]]></message>
</error>
</errors>
</thirtybees>
```

They switched servers and the problem was not on the old server but the new. They say, that everything is as it should be, but I suspect there might be a problem in relation to their Prestashop installation and the php version. I just don't have those details from the client.

Can anyone advise me what to do, especially if they have seen this type of problem before.

Thank you

Comment: It really seems that the problem is in differences between PHP versions.  And also, what version of prestashop we are talking about?

Comment: Well they wont tell me and I don't know how to look it up. Which was why I was speculating on the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is using [Thirtybees](http://thirttybees.com), which is an off shoot of PrestaShop 1.6.

There is a github for webservice issues.  https://github.com/thirtybees/thirtybees/issues/434

Comment: Thanks you for the insight

Answer (score 0):

PHP 7.2 is not in PrestaShop 1.6's officially supported PHP compatibility range (which is 5.2 ~ 7.1).

If your PrestaShop version is below 1.7.5.0, you must to modify content of /home/xyz/public_html/classes/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php, and change the  line `public static $shopIDs;` with `public static $shopIDs =[];`

Explanation: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/commit/8662b3a50eae1ca7e6f6de02b419f123ba2ceee8